# Why are the dates between a given range not getting picked?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am trying to pick dates between ranges. I have hard coded date and month but the year is dynamically concatenated with it. I am trying to pick dates between these ranges from the table but it doesn't always give the dates between the given range.

```
Declare @year varchar(10)
Set @year= '2017-2018'

Declare @YearFrom varchar(15)
Set @YearFrom= (Select SUBSTRING(@year, 1, 4) )
Declare @YearTo varchar(15)
Set @YearTo= (Select SUBSTRING(@year, 6, 9) )

Set @YearFrom= '01-07-'+@YearFrom
Set @YearTo= '30-06-'+@YearTo

Select Convert(varchar(11),c.RegistrationDate,106)  from Contractors c
where Convert(varchar(11),c.RegistrationDate,106) between Convert(varchar(11),@yearFrom,106)
 and Convert(varchar(11),@YearTo,106)
```

the registration date is saved as:

**YYYY-MM-DD e.g. 2017-07-03**

Comment: Don't store dates in varchar, use proper data types!

Comment: it is possible that in those cases when the result is not given  `where date between date1 and date2` the `date1` is bigger than the `date2`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is by using DATEFROMPARTS, where Year, Month and Day inputs are converted into dates, as follows:

```
Declare @year varchar(10)
Set @year= '2017-2018'

Declare @YearFrom int
Set @YearFrom= (Select SUBSTRING(@year, 1, 4) ) 

Declare @YearTo int
Set @YearTo= (Select SUBSTRING(@year, 6, 9) ) 

Declare @StartDate date
Set @StartDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearFrom,1,7)

Declare @EndDate date
Set @EndDate = DATEFROMPARTS(@YearTo,6,30)
```

Now you can use @StartDate and @EndDate in your comparison with the registration date.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to compare dates, you cannot use `VARCHAR` values, you should be using the actual type you are looking for, `DATETIME`.

Second, you have 2 format for dates

- `@YearFrom` and `@YearTo` are `DD-MM-YYYY`, so you need to use `105` in `CONVERT` function
- `RegistrationDate` is `YYYY-MM-DD`, so for this you need to use `120` in `CONVERT` function

With that in mind, please see the query below:

```
    Declare @year varchar(10)
    Set @year= '2017-2018'

    Declare @YearFrom varchar(15)
    Set @YearFrom= (Select SUBSTRING(@year, 1, 4) )
    Declare @YearTo varchar(15)
    Set @YearTo= (Select SUBSTRING(@year, 6, 9) )

    Set @YearFrom= '01-07-'+@YearFrom
    Set @YearTo= '30-06-'+@YearTo

    ;with Contractors AS (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    (VALUES ('2018-05-01'),('2018-07-01')) AS V(RegistrationDate)
    )
    Select *
    from Contractors c
    where Convert(DATETIME,c.RegistrationDate,120) between Convert(DATETIME,@yearFrom,105) and Convert(DATETIME,@YearTo,105)
```

Hope it makes sense.